# Add file names as row name based on condition with R

Tags: r, write.table

I have found some variations to this question, and tried all possibilities but it does not help. I have been able to just extract the content, but I would like to have the file name associated as well at each row in a CSV file: If content ("Flash Point") found in the “.txt” file, extract content and give the “.txt” file name as the associated row name in the csv. If content not find just skip both content and file and go to next extraction. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The issue here is that the row names are given based on a specific condition. Here is the initial code. Thanks a lot for your help

```
for (i in 1:length(txt)){
  doc<-readLines(txt[i])
  doc<-doc[grepl("Flash point",doc)]
  lst[[txt[[i]]]]<-doc %>% stringr::str_extract("(\\d|>).*")
  results<-lst[[txt[[i]]]]
  write.table(results,file = "outputestrod.csv",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE,sep = ",", append = TRUE)
}
```

I am adding an example here
[Content Extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmDZy.png)
[Content Extracted with Files names As row if specific content  value found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vABLi.png)

Result of suggested `results<-paste(txt[i],lst[[txt[[i]]]])`
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXgZa.png)

Comment: Please make a reproducible example. I really have no idea what you're trying to do and your code snippet doesn't help

Comment: Thanks @divibisan for your quick reply. I have edited my post by adding two examples. The first shows that i have been able to extract the content. The second is the desired result: if specific content exist in file extract it and associate the file name. Otherwise skip it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a paste() command to combine two strings, the file name, and the contents of the file.

Try changing the line

```
results<-lst[[txt[[i]]]]
```

to this:

```
results<- paste(txt, lst[[txt[[i]]]] )
```

Comment: Thanks djchapman. With your suggestion we are almost there. The issue is that I have both results (file name + content extracted) in the same cell. I would like to have them in different column in the same row (e.g Cells(1,1)=Filename, Cells(1,2)= Content). I put the results in the initial post. Thanks

Comment: Ok, try results <- data.frame(file = txt[i], content = txt[i],lst[[txt[[i]]]])

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse version of what I think you are trying to do. Consider the resource http://r4ds.had.co.nz/ if you want to learn to code like this. Your loop does not take advantage of R's vector operations.

```
library(tidyverse)

filenames <- dir(your folder)

file_and_content_with_string <- function(filename, string){
  doc<-readLines(filename)
  doc<-doc[grepl(string,doc)]
  file_text <- doc %>% stringr::str_extract("(\\d|>).*")
  results <- data.frame(filename = filename, content = file_text)
}

all_results <- map_df(filenames, function(x) file_and_content_with_string(x, "Flash point")) 

write_csv(all_results, "outputestrod.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resource, I went through it and its looks great. I also tries the above but I get the error message "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘mnormt’". I tried to insert "Dependencies=TRUE" or "cellranger" as suggested by other post but nothing work

Comment: Yes I did install the package first, and then got the error while running the library. Now I closed everything and reopened R, tried to run it again . This is what I GET :  installed.packages("tidyverse")
     Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built
>  Thanks

Comment: I don't know the cause of that error. If tidyverse is a dead end, did you try the line I suggested using the old for loop, in the comments of the first answer?  results <- data.frame(file = txt[i], content = txt[i],lst[[txt[[i]]]])

Comment: I ran it  This is the error I got : Error in data.frame(file = txt[i], content = txt[i], lst[[txt[[i]]]]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0.   Is there anything missing? Thanks a lot for your time . very appreciated

Comment: Hi djchapman, I tried the tidyverse , and it is now working. The only concern is the last line of the code that does not work . If I am able to solve this line i will be okay.This is what I receive when I run it : > all_results <- map_df(filenames, function(x) file_and_content_with_string(x, "Flash point"))
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
 
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection